# How to make aggregation like count in scala

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

Helloo,

I have stuck with collections in scala. I have a list like that:

```
val a2 = List(("C",2.0,288,1978),
  ("C",2.5,307,1978),
  ("C",3.0,312,1978),
  ("C",2.5,377,1978),
  ("C",1.0,571,1978),
  ("H"," ",288,1978),
    ("H",2.5,307, 1978),
  ("A",4.0,187,2003),
  ("A",3.0,260, 2003))
```

My aim is to use group by with 1st and 4th value (Genre and year) and to count 2nd and 3rd values. Then, a new column should be added to make count_2nd/count_3rd. The final look should be something like that:

```
C, 1978 -> 5, 5 , 1.0
H, 1978 -> 1, 2, 0.5
A, 2003 -> 2, 2, 1.0
```

I have tried that:

```
a2.flatMap(row => row._2.map( nm => (row._1,nm.rating,nm.userId,row._3)))
```

but IDE didn't allow to add something like that .count(i => i._2). I guess I am in a bad way to do it.

There should be also null value in data and in the 6th line of data there is a null value. By considering null values, I expect to have some different values in count_2nd/count_3rd.

Is it possible in scala and if it is possible, I will be appreciated :)

Comment: 1) It is definitely possible 2) what have you tried 3) Why `Horror` is `1, 2, 0.5` ? 4) should not `count_2nd/count_3rd` be always 1?

Comment: I have tried that: a2.flatMap(row => row._2.map( nm => (row._1,nm.rating,nm.userId,row._3))) but IDE didn't allow to add somthing like that .count(i => i._2). I guess I am in a bad way to do it. 3) There should be null value in data and in the 6th line of data there is a null value. 4) By considering null values, I expect to have some different values

Comment: Please add it to the question.

Comment: Also can you please add compilable code to the queston?

Comment: @GuruStron I did it. The whole code is so long with classes and it is messy but I modified val a2 as compilable

Comment: In 6th row null or empty row? What do you mean count? May be distinct count or not null count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need group by - use group by:

```scala
val a2: List[(String, Double, Int, Option[Int])] = List(("Comedy", 2.0, 288, Some(1978)),
    ("Comedy", 2.5, 307, Some(1978)),
    ("Comedy", 3.0, 312, Some(1978)),
    ("Comedy", 2.5, 377, Some(1978)),
    ("Comedy", 1.0, 571, Some(1978)),
    ("Horror", Double.NaN, 288, Some(1978)),
    ("Horror", 2.5, 307, Some(1978)),
    ("Adventure", 4.0, 187, Some(2003)),
    ("Adventure", 3.0, 260, Some(2003)))

val result = a2.groupBy(t => (t._1, t._4))
    .view
    .mapValues(lst => (lst.filter(!_._2.isNaN).length, lst.filter(!_._3.isNaN).length)) // transform grouping into tuple with needed counts 
    .mapValues(t => (t._1, t._2, t._1.toFloat / t._2)) // "add" 3rd column
    .toMap

println(result) // prints Map((Horror,Some(1978)) -> (1,2,0.5), (Comedy,Some(1978)) -> (5,5,1.0), (Adventure,Some(2003)) -> (2,2,1.0))
```

Comment: @bbgghh was glad to help! `groupBy` returns you map from key to collection of matched values, which then you process with `mapValues`, firs time - to count "valid" values (note that I used `Double.NaN` instead of `" "` to have correct types) and second `mapValues` is used to "extend" tuple with calculated data.